# Android /dev/uinput does not work

Tags: android, android-ndk, linux-device-driver, user-input, vnc-server

I'm trying to control Android by writing data into /dev/uinput. For example, if I enter 'A' on my desktop, the codes will write something according to key_code into uinput and Android should behave like I input an 'A' on the phone. I am following the codes in [RemoteInput](http://www.math.bme.hu/~morap/RemoteInput/). I tested on Nexus 4 with JB 4.2 system. All the ioctls return positive results, which means it should work. However, when I put in an 'A', the Android only seems to refresh the virtual keyboard and does not input anything.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to "register" the supported keys using `ioctl(m_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, key)`. For A, you should use `KEY_A`, which is defined in `linux/input.h` (`#define KEY_A 30`) and not `KEYCODE_A`, which is a different code. In my experience, `/dev/uinput` on Android works with Linux key codes.

You should:

1. open `/dev/uinput`
2. `ioctl(m_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY)` - support EV_KEY event
3. `ioctl(m_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_SYN)` - support EV_SYN event
4. `ioctl(m_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, key)` - support `key` - for each keycode that you want to support
5. create `uinput_user_dev` structure and populate it, then write that structure to `/dev/uinput` file descriptor (see below)
6. call `ioctl(m_fd, UI_DEV_CREATE)` to create this device; the m_fd will now point to newly created device.

Do monitor `logcat` output and check if the device will be created successfully. It will take a generic keychar map and key layout, since no keymap is defined. If you want to define it, look into `/system/usr/keychars` and `/system/usr/keylayout`.

---

#### Create uinput device

```
uinput_user_dev uidev;
memset(&uidev, 0, sizeof(uidev));
snprintf(uidev.name, UINPUT_MAX_NAME_SIZE, "uinput-test");
uidev.id.bustype = BUS_USB;
uidev.id.vendor  = 0x1212;
uidev.id.product = 0xabab;
uidev.id.version = 3;
write(m_fd, &uidev, sizeof(uidev)
```

Comment: @user1659072 Did this work for you? If so, please mark answer as correct. Would be great to see a short code example, how to implement that.